# How to run a script after client validation in asp.net mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am disabling my submit buttons when submitting a form, for preventing the user to submit the form multiple times.

```
$(function ()
{
    $("form").submit(function ()
    {
        $(":submit", this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });
});
```

But if the client validation fails I want to enable the button again.
I am using asp.net mvc unobtrusive client validation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery One event as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4539302/asp-net-mvc-how-to-prevent-double-clic-submit-with-jquery-validate-unobtrusive).

Most solutions to this issue revolve around testing $("form").valid() - you could probably use this in your function to determine whether to disable the submit button.

Comment: If it is the only form on the page, there should be e global boolean variable "Page_IsValid" you can use to determine if the button should be disabled. The client side validation API is explained here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479045.aspx#aspplusvalid_clientside

Answer (score 0):

You have to check if there is any error before disabling the submit button

```
$('#myform').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).find('.input-validation-error').length == 0) {
        $(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

Hope it helps!